# How to use checkbox and textview in list view together?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am going to use `CheckBox` and `TextView` in list view. I use this xml code for aligning `ListView` items:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Item_Listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="gfhfgh"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want align `TextView` to right and `CheckBox` to left.

Comment: Why do you even need the `TextView`? `CheckBox` is an extension of `TextView` and supports i.e. `android:text` by itself. Since we're talking in the context of `ListView`, you may also want to check out [`CheckedTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html).

Comment: I want use checkboxs for select and delete listView Items

Comment: You right . I can not touch textviews in list view now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Item_Listview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="gfhfgh"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you.I use this and add (android:gravity="right")  to textview code .It solved

Comment: Rajan KS: I cannot touch the textview now. I can touch checkbox and checked it But Onclicklistener don't work now

Comment: use `onCheckedchangeListener` for your `Checkbox`

Comment: I wrote OnItemClickListener event for  listview that this don't work now.I can touch checkbox and checked it

Answer (score 2):

You don't need such a complicated layout. Checkbox ships all elements you need. You can use this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="someText"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/someDrawable"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add textview to linearlayout like this

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView_Item_Listview"
android:weight="0.5"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="3dp"
android:text="gfhfgh"
android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `RelativeLayout` for e.g

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignParentLeft="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Item_Listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:alignParentRight="true" 
    android:text="gfhfgh"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Item_Listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="gfhfgh"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OR**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="gfhfgh" />

</LinearLayout>
```

you can set the text to `CheckBox` instead of using other `TextView`